# How to Read Hive Internal Table with PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hive, hive-metastore

pyspark cannot read hive internal table. I want to know can I read?

**Spark 2.3.1**

```
scala> spark.table("c").show
+---+
| id|
+---+
| 1|
| 2|
+---+

scala> spark.table("c").count
res5: Long = 2
```

**Spark 2.4.0**

```
scala> spark.table("c").show
19/01/18 17:00:49 WARN HiveMetastoreCatalog: Unable to infer schema for table perftest_be.c from file format ORC (inference mode: INFER_AND_SAVE). Using metastore schema.
+---+
| id|
+---+
+---+


scala> spark.table("c").count
res3: Long = 0
```